# Iterate over a txt file of urls to scrape them

Tags: python, web-scraping, url

I currently have a function that takes in a url string, read it to find x information and store it as a json file:

```
def log_scrape(url):

    HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246'}

    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    data = soup.find_all('script')[8]
    dataString = data.text.rstrip()

    logData = re.findall(r'{.*}', dataString)

    try:
        urlLines = url.split('/')
        if len(urlLines) < 5:
            bossName = urlLines[3]
        elif len(urlLines) == 5:
            bossName = urlLines[4]
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error' + str(e)
    
    tag = bossName.split('_')
    bossTag = tag[1]

    try:
        # Wing_1
        if bossTag == 'vg':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_1\Valley_Guardian'
        elif bossTag == 'gors':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_1\Gorseval_The_Multifarious'
        elif bossTag == 'sab':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_1\Sabetha'
        # Wing_2
        elif bossTag == 'sloth':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_2\Slothasor'
        elif bossTag == 'matt':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_2\Mathias'
        # Wing_3
        elif bossTag == 'kc':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_3\Keep_Construct'
        elif bossTag == 'xera':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_3\Xera'
        # Wing_4
        elif bossTag == 'cairn':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_4\Cairn_The_Indomitable'
        elif bossTag == 'mo':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_4\Mursaat_Overseer'
        elif bossTag == 'sam':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_4\Samarog'
        elif bossTag == 'dei':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_4\Deimos'
        # Wing_5
        elif bossTag == 'sh':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_5\Soulless_Horror_Deesmina'
        elif bossTag == 'dhuum':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_5\Dhuum'
        # Wing_6
        elif bossTag == 'ca':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_6\Conjured_Amalgamate'
        elif bossTag == 'twinlargos':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_6\Twin_Largos'
        elif bossTag == 'qadim':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_6\Qadim'
        # Wing_7
        elif bossTag == 'adina':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_7\Cardinal_Adina'
        elif bossTag == 'sabir':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_7\Cardinal_Sabir'
        elif bossTag == 'prlqadim' or bossTag == 'qpeer':
            pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_7\Qadim_The_Peerless'
    except:
        pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data' 

    with open(f'{pathName}\{bossName}.json', 'w') as f:
        for line in logData:
            jsonFile = f.write(line)
    return jsonFile
pass
```

However, this makes the process quite slow, so I wanted to try and use a txt file, loop over it and run de function, the txt file looks like this:

```
https://gw2wingman.nevermindcreations.de/logContent/20220829-151336_matt_kill
https://gw2wingman.nevermindcreations.de/logContent/20220831-214520_sabir_kill
https://gw2wingman.nevermindcreations.de/logContent/20220831-190128_sabir_kill
```

I tried using a for loop:

```
with open('gw2_urls.txt', 'r') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        print(log_scrape(url))
```

But it always return an error 'List out of index' in the line "data = soup.find_all('script')[8]", nonetheless, if I do this one by one, this error doesn't appear.

If you have any idea why this could be happening and how I could speed this process up it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, do you want the links from the data? You seem to be only getting one from `soup.find_all('script')[8]` and that is if it exists at all. This is a list of all elements that are of tag script. Example for `<a>` and `href` attribute:

```py
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
# http://example.com/tillie
```

This can be changed to with

```py
log_data = [a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a')]
```

And later print it into a file as follows:

```py
with open('gw2_urls.txt', 'w') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        urls.write(log_data + "\n")
```

Comment: The data inside the url is quite weird, those links are actually the src of an iframe, so all information I need is stored in that specific script. The data I need is actually a JSON data stored in var _logData

Comment: Yeah understand, but if the problem is with depth, this can be still done with a few chain searches on the DOM, including starting with `script` and then extracting the exact info. Would suggest checking https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all documentation, and the ways you can find elements

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of reading lines in text file with python would be:

```
with open('gw2_urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()
    for url in urls:
        print(log_scrape(url))
```

For more details on `readlines()` see https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp

Comment: Barry also changed the reading, so I won't address it in my answer. This is the correct way to do it.